# Thread unable to acquire lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I m new to multi-threading.I was trying out this simple code to learn about locks. I have created two threads out of which Thread 2 starts but is unable to acquire lock.Only Timer 1 keeps on acquiring and releasing the lock.

```
import threading
import time

lock=threading.Lock()

def timer(name,delay):
    print "Timer:"+name+"started"


    while(True):
        lock.acquire()  
        print "Timer:"+name+" acquired the lock"
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "Timer:"+name+" releasing the lock"
        lock.release()  

def Main():
    t1=threading.Thread(target=timer, args=("Timer1",.1))
    t2=threading.Thread(target=timer, args=("Timer2",.1))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    print "Main Complete"


if __name__=="__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: What is the output of the code? Probably the first thread is immediately grabbing the lock again when the loop repeats, so the second thread is never able to grab it.

Comment: yes Timer1 is grabbing the lock again and again

Comment: What happens if you add an extra delay after the release?

Comment: yes it works fine now after adding the delay. Any other way to get around this?

Comment: When I run the code the second thread occasionally is able to grab the lock. It depends on what you want to happen -- with your code it will be a random free-for-all for which thread goes when. What else would you want them to do?

Comment: With me Thread 2 never acquires .Just wanted to know if I had to put a delay every time I release a lock for some other thread to acquire it?